# Why do jasper reports generate multiple tables instead of one?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to use jasperreport to generate pdf file with table in it, my java code is as follows:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/main/resources/report1.jrxml");
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<Info>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    Info info = new Info();
    info.setAccountCode("abc");
    info.setAccountName("test");
    infos.add(info);                
}

JRBeanCollectionDataSource beans = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(infos);
params.put("tableSource", infos);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report , params, beans);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,"jasper.pdf");
```

in jrxml file, I created a parameter `tableSource` (its type is List), added two fields `accountName` and `accountCode`, added a 'Table' report element, also created

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{tableSource})
```

in table properties, the full jrxml file is :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6fa4b189-7e18-456b-9307-710a8d6972c1">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="20"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="6d5cf195-8b52-4dfe-9f53-9e3eb5be5db3">
        <field name="accountCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="accountName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="tableSource" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="accountCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" x="108" y="30" width="450" height="50" uuid="c7628262-8e54-4c62-b977-175f6aea984e"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 1" uuid="8beea930-93ae-4fa8-826b-cebfebef3a86">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{tableSource})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="0155325f-f82b-4b89-849c-dff724c771a9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="ea43a2ac-624e-4c44-a53c-60f79a2a4cd3"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Account Code]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="28ac521c-37bf-4cfc-80ad-35a380e32d9a"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="STSong-Light" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="9249d41a-f7af-4abf-9163-0a15d0a621a8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="81274afc-cb28-4251-8e9d-8ffe2466d2dc"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Account Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="5876bb0e-cc9d-4d34-a2ba-483016846752"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="STSong-Light" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accountName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I expect it generate one table like next :

```
Account Code  Account Name
abc           test
abc           test
```

However, the real result is there are 2 tables generated like following :

```
Account Code  Account Name
abc           test
abc           test

Account Code  Account Name
abc           test
abc           test
```

why there are two same table generated?

I'm using iReport 5.6.0, jasperreport 6.2.2

Comment: You have 2 rounds of iterations in main report (Detail band)

Comment: Pass a new JREmptyDataSource(1) to the report.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, thanks your tip, it works, may I ask why I should pass a JREmptyDataSource rather than JRCollectionDataSource?Does it mean that I always pass JREmptyDataSource if I use Table component in jrxml?

Comment: @frank, I have posted an answer to explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a [JREmptyDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JREmptyDataSource.html) with 1 record to the `JasperFillManager`

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report , params, new JREmptyDataSource(1));
```

**why?**

Jasper Reports iterate's the `detail` band on the datasource you pass to the `JasperFillManager`, hence it will create as many detail bands as records in your `JRBeanCollectionDataSource beans`. In your case you do not want this since you are passing this datasource as a parameter to be used by the `<jr:table>` component. Your setup is to display detail band once (1 record) with a jr:table that iterates on a datasource passed as parameter and the easiest way to get 1 record is a `new JREmptyDataSource(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You've put your `Table` in the `Details` band.

The `Details` band is generated for every row out of the result. Since you have two rows of data, you also get two tables.

Try moving the `Table` into another band like `Summary`, `Column Footer` or what makes sense in your case.

Comment: thank you your answer, I tried to move table to other part, but the overflow occur some times, e.g. when the data list size is 20

Comment: Overflow? I thought you get two tables?

Comment: just one table, if my data list size is 10, it's correct, but if my data list size is 20, it throws overflow exception.